# Mule how to ignore GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution

Tags: mule, log4j2, cloudhub

Keep getting warnings like below in CloudHub. CloudHub logs are restricted to 30days and 100mb. This is a problem as it clutters logs and important ones are lost. I know there is a way to restrict/suppress this GRIZZLY0013 warning in LOG4J2 configuration but I forgot it and can't find it anywhere. Is there a way to disable it?

Mule version - 3.9.2

```
Worker-0     [app-name].HTTP_Default_Listener_Configuration.worker.01     WARN
GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path parameter must start with /
    at org.mule.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:26)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpListenerRegistry$ServerAddressRequestHandlerRegistry.findRequestHandler(HttpListenerRegistry.java:222)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpListenerRegistry.getRequestHandler(HttpListenerRegistry.java:83)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:540)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:126)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:32)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the package org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain to ERROR level so the warning is ignored. However first you should check if the HTTP listener configuration really is not starting with a path and fix it.

Comment: That is it, thank you! Will save it in my notes this time!
HTTP Listener Configuration Base Path is empty
HTTP Listener Connector Path starts with /v1.0

Comment: I'm not sure if it the warning refers to the received URI then.

Comment: It was a bug in earlier Mule versions but it is fixed so I am not sure what could cause it :/